# How do I hide a div element for subsequent visits, by the same user, to my website?

Tags: javascript

I have a div element that I'd only like to show when the user arrives for the first time on my website.

My website is located here: http://w3programmer.cf

I understand that I need to use display:none to hide this, but I am unsure exactly of what is required to track that this is not the user's first time visiting the website.

If, for instance, I'd like to remove my `soup-nav` (The arrow at the bottom) how would I do this?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help] to see how to ask questions that will be better recieved. For a start all code relevant for the question needs to be in the question itself, preferably as a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

you have to do this with javascript.
Set a cookie when the user first visits your website and hide the element when the user has already visited your site.

Example:
add this script anywhere on your website (e.g.: at the end of body)

```
<script>
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited=true") >= 0){
    document.getElementById("soup-nav").style.display = 'none';
  }else{
    document.cookie = 'visited=true; expires=Mon, 14 Aug 2028 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
  }
</script>
```